# Unable to apply build modifier and import animation into Three.js project

Tags: three.js, build-modifier

I am new to Blender and WeGL. Sorry if this question has been asked  before and already solved.

I am working on a project for my website. I have text object animated on location, rotation and scale, however I am unable to apply "build modifier" to this animation. It's working perfectly fine until I apply the modifier to the animation.

Is there anyway that I can work this out and import the animation into the Three.js project(glb/gltf file) ??

[image]

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you upload a simplified blend file where we can see your problem?

Comment: @Chris, I have created a simplified example and uploaded it. I added the build modifier, but I have not applied so that you can see it stop working after you apply the modifier. Please take a look.

Comment: i applied it and it still worked...what blender version are u using?

Comment: It is 2.93.0. I am sure I am using the up to date one. I am probably not applying the modifier properly. Could I ask you to upload the one you edited ?? Thank you.